# How to fix "Error at XMLHttpRequest.send angular universal"

Tags: angular-universal, angular9

Аfter compiling the application, I get this error several times
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeQho.png)

text error:

ERROR Error

```
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:169324:19)
    at Observable.rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:19023:17)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:154852:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:154838:22)
    at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:162245:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:154833:31)
    at scheduleTask (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:97108:32)
    at Observable.rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:97170:13)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:154852:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\seva-\projects\pileuniversal\dist\pileuniversal\server\main.js:154838:22)
```

I'm not importing anything in `app.server.module` after creating ssr
Was problem with localStorage and window with DOM, but solition is exist

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please include a code sample or a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to do? It is very difficult for anyone to help you with just a stack trace.

Comment: Can you show an example of your service calls?

Answer (score 4):

I face the very same problem. You may check this article

https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/general/framework-and-features/ssr-rendering.html

The issue for XMLHttpRequest.send comes from the fact that this "object", does not exist for the Node server.

I advise You to track where Your error comes from. In my case, it was from ngx-translate module, which was trying to get the JSON files via XMLHttpRequest. To solve the issue You have to:

1. Identify from where this call has been made
2. Apply interceptors which will handle the request properly

In my case, I follow this tutorial: https://itnext.io/angular-universal-how-to-add-multi-language-support-68d83f6dfc4d

I add the interceptor and solve the issue.

Hope that helps

Comment: does this still work on angular 13? i tried the solution above, still having an error..

Answer (score 1):

I Had this problem, and just now I changed the URL for my requests

from

`'/assets/data/products.json'`

to

`'http://localhost...'.`

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: https://www.andremonteiro.pt/ngx-translate-angular-universal-ssr/

**plus**

add to package.json

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
}
```